# can not serialize data class in data class with objectmapper and kotlin

Tags: kotlin, objectmapper

Can not serialize data class in data class with `kotlin` and `objectmapper`

I'am using  `kotlin version "1.3.72"` and
`com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin version  "2.11.2"`.

This is my classes

```
data class A(val b: B)

data class B(val name: String)


val a = A(B(name = "name")

objectMapper.writeValueAsString(a) // << failed!!!
```

Why couldn't serialize?

Comment: What's the error that you get?

Comment: Could you show us your configuration of objectMapper, maybe you don't have kotlinModule included?